# How to check multiple id's from results IN multiple id columns in a row in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have an invoice table. The invoice has an owner and customer, both id fields which link to a resource table. The resource table contains businesses which might have 'child' businesses under them. I have a query that checks if the current business is in the owner_id or customer_id like so:

```
SELECT * FROM invoices i WHERE @BusinessId IN ( i.owner_id, i.customer_id )
```

The problem I have at the moment is that I need to verify if the business or its child businesses are in the owner_id or customer_id. We have a function that returns a table containing the business ids from the resource table if I query it like so:

```
select business_id from  dbo.vfn_child_business(@BusinessId , 'Y')
```

The 'Y' parameter basically returns the main parent along with the child business id's in the results (essentially looking for child businesses of a business and including itself).

I can't figure out how to query to say

```
SELECT * from Invoices
where ANY OF MY RESULTS FROM CHILD BUSINESS FUNCTION IN ( i.owner_id, i.customer_id ).
```

I've tried:

```
... WHERE (select business_id 
           from  dbo.vfn_child_business(@BusinessId , 'Y'))
    IN ( i.owner_id, i.customer_id )
```

But I get this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but the `EXISTS` predicate might help here:

```
WITH children AS
    (SELECT business_id
     FROM dbo.vfn_child_business(@BusinessId , 'Y'))
SELECT
    i.*
FROM
    Invoices AS i
WHERE
    EXISTS
        (SELECT 1
         FROM children
         WHERE children.business_id IN ( i.owner_id, i.customer_id ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just join the function to the table?

```
SELECT
  invoices.*
FROM
  invoices
INNER JOIN
  dbo.vfn_child_business(@BusinessId , 'Y')  AS child_business
    ON invoices.owner_id    = child_business.business_id
    OR invoices.customer_id = child_business.business_id
```

If this can cause duplicates, use DISTINCT or a GROUP BY.

Comment: Not yet, but I've simplified my query ALOT. This is a small part of a 400 line query spanning about 15 tables. :) I'm leaving for the day now but I'll try to see if I can include it in a join tomorrow. My initial thoughts are that I can't though.

Comment: Table Valued Functions can certainly be joined to, so this should certainly be possible.  If it proves to be an issue, leave a note here and I'll have a look.